# Animation only works in firefox, in other browsers animation position and appearance changes

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Animation of falling drops works perfectly in firefox browser, but in chrome and edge does not work.

The animation works by hovering the mouse over a spot.

In firefox, you can see that these drops are a liquid that extends.
In other browsers, it is a circle that drops down.

I added animations and keyframes to compatible all browsers, it did not help.
In addition to this, the position of the droplets also changes.

Thank you for any help and best regards

```css
body
    {
        background-color:#5c5c5c;
        height:1100px;
    }

    #drip
    {
     position: absolute;    
    }

    .path-choose
    {
        pointer-events: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
    }


    .crop
    {
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(99% 30%, 97% 18%, 91% 13%, 86% 13%, 82% 15%, 77% 17%, 72% 19%, 68% 19%, 63% 17%, 58% 11%, 54% 8%, 49% 10%, 44% 15%, 39% 21%, 35% 24%, 30% 25%, 26% 22%, 21% 14%, 17% 8%, 12% 3%, 8% 1%, 3% 4%, 1% 15%, 1% 25%, 2% 34%, 5% 41%, 8% 45%, 11% 52%, 11% 62%, 12% 72%, 14% 81%, 17% 86%, 21% 88%, 26% 88%, 30% 84%, 34% 82%, 37% 81%, 42% 84%, 46% 88%, 50% 92%, 54% 95%, 57% 97%, 61% 98%, 65% 95%, 68% 89%, 71% 84%, 75% 84%, 79% 84%, 83% 84%, 87% 80%, 87% 70%, 87% 61%, 89% 54%, 93% 49%, 96% 44%, 99% 39%); 
        clip-path: polygon(99% 30%, 97% 18%, 91% 13%, 86% 13%, 82% 15%, 77% 17%, 72% 19%, 68% 19%, 63% 17%, 58% 11%, 54% 8%, 49% 10%, 44% 15%, 39% 21%, 35% 24%, 30% 25%, 26% 22%, 21% 14%, 17% 8%, 12% 3%, 8% 1%, 3% 4%, 1% 15%, 1% 25%, 2% 34%, 5% 41%, 8% 45%, 11% 52%, 11% 62%, 12% 72%, 14% 81%, 17% 86%, 21% 88%, 26% 88%, 30% 84%, 34% 82%, 37% 81%, 42% 84%, 46% 88%, 50% 92%, 54% 95%, 57% 97%, 61% 98%, 65% 95%, 68% 89%, 71% 84%, 75% 84%, 79% 84%, 83% 84%, 87% 80%, 87% 70%, 87% 61%, 89% 54%, 93% 49%, 96% 44%, 99% 39%);
        z-index: 3;
        pointer-events: auto;

    }


    .view
    {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }


    @keyframes fade-in {0% {opacity: 0;}100% {opacity: 1;}}

    @keyframes drop {0% {bottom: 0px;opacity: 1;}80% {opacity: 1;}100% {opacity: 1;bottom: -200px;}}

    @keyframes wave {0% {background-position: 0 160px;background-size: 170px 300px;}100% {background-position: 500px -18px;background-size: 250px 150px;}}


    .drops {
      -webkit-filter: url('#liquid');
      filter: url('#liquid');
      -moz-filter: url('#liquid');
      -o-filter: url('#liquid');
      -ms-filter: url('#liquid');
      position:relative;
      top:0;
      left:5px;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0;
      animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -moz-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -webkit-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -o-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -ms-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      animation-delay: 1.5s;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      line-height: 120px;
      margin: auto;

    }

    .drops2 {
      -webkit-filter: url('#liquid');
      filter: url('#liquid');
      -moz-filter: url('#liquid');
      -o-filter: url('#liquid');
      -ms-filter: url('#liquid');
      position:relative;
      top:-97px;
      left:145px;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0;
      animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -moz-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -webkit-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -o-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -ms-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      line-height: 120px;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .drops3 {
      -webkit-filter: url('#liquid');
      filter: url('#liquid');
      -moz-filter: url('#liquid');
      -o-filter: url('#liquid');
      -ms-filter: url('#liquid');
      position:relative;
      top:-240px;
      left:230px;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0;
      animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -moz-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -webkit-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -o-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      -ms-animation: fade-in .1s linear .4s forwards;
      line-height: 120px;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .drop1 {
      width: 60px;
      height: 16px;
      bottom: 2px;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    .drop2 {
      animation: drop 1.3s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -moz-animation: drop 1.3s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: drop 1.3s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -o-animation: drop 1.3s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -ms-animation: drop 1.3s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
    }
    .drop3 {
      animation: drop 1.6s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -moz-animation: drop 1.6s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: drop 1.6s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -o-animation: drop 1.6s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -ms-animation: drop 1.6s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
    }
    .drop4 {
      animation: drop 1.47s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -moz-animation: drop 1.47s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: drop 1.47s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -o-animation: drop 1.47s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
      -ms-animation: drop 1.47s cubic-bezier(1,.19,.66,.12) .5s infinite;
    }

    .drop1 , .drop2, .drop3, .drop4 {
      width: 21px;
      height: 24px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #ffc476;
    }

    .drop2,.drop3,.drop4  /*,.drops, .drops2,.drops3 */
    {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    display:none;
    }

    .display:hover .drop2,.display:hover .drop3,.display:hover .drop4,.display:hover .drops,.display:hover .drops2,.display:hover .drops3{
        animation-play-state: running;
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Candle Wax</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Candle">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
                
            <div class="path-choose">
             <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oSu6.png" width="343px" height="142px" class="view">
             <div  class="display">
             <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oSu6.png" width="343px" height="142px" class="crop" ondragstart="return false;">
                    
                    
                 <div id="drip">
                     <div class="drops">
                        <div class="drop1"></div>
                        <div class="drop2"></div>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="drops2">
                        <div class="drop1"></div>
                        <div class="drop3"></div>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="drops3">
                        <div class="drop1"></div>
                        <div class="drop4"></div>  
                    </div>
                    
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                      <defs>
                        <filter id="liquid">
                          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
                          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="liquid" />
                        </filter>
                      </defs>
                    </svg>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, filters like this are not working on [SVG elements](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_filter_svg) yet

Comment: It was sad to hear, maybe I could use something as an alternative? Or could I make this effect visible only to firefox?

Comment: I'm getting tired of why the position changes as well );
thanks for your reply